# What are $(S,\Sigma)$-CCCs?

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, category-theory

I was reading [this](http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/images/8/8c/CS522-Fall-2018-PL-CCC.pdf) and I was trying to understand the definition of $(S,\Sigma)$-CCC. The first requirement says:

> a mapping [[_]] : S → |C|, associating some object [[s]] ∈ |C| to
>   any s ∈ S;

which I find very confusing and having a hard time understanding what it means. What is $S$ and what is $\Sigma$?

why do all the other requirements mean intuitively?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of $S$ and $\Sigma$ is defined on slide 6. $S$ is a set of base types (for example, natural numbers $\mathbb N$, Booleans $\mathbb N$, etc.): these are just formal symbols. $\Sigma$ is a set of operators, which included constants and functions (for example, $0 : \mathbb N$, $\text{true} : \mathbb B$, $\text{not} : \mathbb B \to \mathbb B$, etc.): these are pairs of an element of $S$ and a formal symbol. In the definition on slide 7, they seem to be limiting the operators to just constants.

The mapping $⟦-⟧ : S \to \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal C)$ gives us an interpretation of a base type in the category $\mathcal C$: given any type $A \in S$, we have an object $⟦A⟧ \in \mathcal C$ interpreting that type.

They overload notation and also define a function $⟦-⟧: \Sigma \to \mathcal C^\to$. We interpret each constant $(c : A) \in \Sigma$ as a morphism $⟦c⟧: 1 \to ⟦A⟧$, where $1$ is the terminal object (called $\star$ in the lecture slides). This aligns with the usual interpretation of terms $\Gamma \vdash t : A$ as morphisms $⟦t⟧ : ⟦\Gamma⟧ \to ⟦A⟧$.

Together, both of these mappings $⟦-⟧$ allow us to interpret a signature for a simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus inside a cartesian-closed category, which is the first step in showing the equivalence between simply-typed $\lambda$-calculi and cartesian-closed categories.

Comment: Your answer ends abruptly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: thank you, I've fixed the answer. (I'm not quite sure how I managed to do that!)